# Alert trigger after multiple drop events

Tags: jquery, jquery-droppable, jquery-draggable

I gotta admit, I am pretty much a noob, but I have been struggling with this one. I've got to trigger the `if` after both drops have happened, right now it triggers on load. What am I missing there?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: "#droppable",
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "#draggable",
        drop: function() {
            $("#whistle").get(0).play();
            $(this).data(droppable)
        }
    });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: "#droppable",
    });
    $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
        accept: "#draggable2",
        drop: function() {
            $("#whistle").get(0).play();
            $(this).data(droppable2)
        }
    });
    if ($.queue(2)) {
        $("#whistle2").get(0).play();
        alert ("done!")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two `$.Deferred`s and their `promise`-objects to trigger your handler:

```
$(function() {

    var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
    var dfd2 = $.Deferred();

    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: "#droppable",
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: "#draggable",
        drop: function() {
            $("#whistle").get(0).play();
            $(this).data(droppable);
            dfd1.resolve();
        }
    });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        snap: "#droppable",
    });
    $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
        accept: "#draggable2",
        drop: function() {
            $("#whistle").get(0).play();
            $(this).data(droppable2);
            dfd2.resolve();
        }
    });
    //this will trigger when both dfds have been resolved
    $.when(dfd1.promise(), dfd2.promise()).then(function(){
        $("#whistle2").get(0).play();
        alert ("done!")
    });
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4RGZ/) for a demo (click both buttons and see the magic happen!) and read about [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: Thanks a totally awesomesauce bunch! I've been battling with this for half a night last night. Now to read the documentation. :) Thanks again.